# Why are numbers removed in a regex.ReplaceAllString()

Tags: go

This [play](http://play.golang.org/p/GoJhfazkHP) clearly demonstrates my predicament.

Ultimately I'm trying to split an unruly string into words. To me "2015" is a word and so is "$100" but if the input is "One. 2wo, (three)" I want [One 2wo three]. Because go doesn't allow a Unicode aware regex I thought I'd first remove all "junk characters" and then use `strings.Fields()`

The problem is that any numbers are stripped:

```
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`[\[\](){}"?!,-:;,']`)
fmt.Println(reg.ReplaceAllString("one 1 zer0", ""))
// outputs "one  zer" when I'd expect "one 1 zer0" :(
```

Comment: You don't need regexp to remove a set of runes from a string. [`strings.Map()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map) is your friend (note the mapping function can return <0 to indicate runes to drop, the func could be a simple literal wrapping some [`unicode.IsXXX`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/) call). You probably can do want you want with [`strings.FieldsFunc()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc) directly specifying how you want the input split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[,-:]` matches all characters in the range `,`–`:`. This range happens to contain all ASCII digits (see [ascii(7)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ascii+7)). Put the `-` at the end instead:

```
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`[\[\](){}"?!,:;,'-]`)
```

Comment: That's both annoying and nifty at the same time. Thanks!